Problems when rebasing because of an untracked file
I want to rebase a branch into the main branch so I do
git checkout MyAwesomeBranch
git rebase main

The problem is that I get
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
.git/rebase-apply/patch:68: trailing whitespace.
        
.git/rebase-apply/patch:72: trailing whitespace.
        
warning: 2 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    captioning/trial_image.py
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0003 trial
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".

I am not sure but I think the problem is that later I make captioning/trial_image.py  become untracked.
How can I overcome this?

You're encountering a couple of issues during a git rebase. Here's how to address them:
The warning about whitespace errors informs you that there are lines with trailing whitespace. You can prevent these warnings by configuring Git to automatically trim trailing whitespace:
git config --global core.whitespace trailing-space,space-before-tab
git config --global apply.whitespace fix

The error message indicates that there are untracked files in your working directory that the merge would overwrite. To resolve this, you have two options:
If captioning/trial_image.py is not needed, you can remove it. If it's needed, move it to another location.
rm captioning/trial_image.py # Remove the file

If these files should be part of the repository, add them to the staging area and commit them before continuing with the rebase.
git add captioning/trial_image.py
git commit -m "Add trial_image.py"

After resolving the conflicts or moving/removing the untracked files, you can continue with the rebase process:
git rebase --continue


this file was added in Myawesomebranch but then commits later deleted. If I remove it will it cause problems later when trying to delete it?

Also I tried removing it, but then later git status showed no change, so do I just make git rebase --continue?

Ok what I did was git add captioning/trial_image.py and then git rebase --continue. It seemed to work ... I hope

Did you solve the issue, i just see the comments...

@KansaiRobot Do you know what the file is good for? Why it exists? Why you added it and then you removed it? You should know all that. Just adding a file with git add because it lets you get over a problem by happenstance and then hoping the best is usually not the way to go.

it is a file that I was originally supposed to include in the repo but decided to excluded afterwards

@KansaiRobot you should delete it if it is not belong to the repository.

It is eliminated in a following commit of the branch I am rebasing

I think the proper way here would have been to do an interactive rebase, amend the commit where the file was added to not add the file, and continue the rebase.
